# Connecting to Second Generation MySQL from a Tomcat webapp on a GCE instance

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, google-cloud-sql

I'm working on a "pilot" installation of a webapp that runs in Tomcat, in a GCE instance, that talks to a Second Generation MySQL server. As I get closer to making it operational, I'm now running into something I'm having trouble making sense of.

Given:

The application is in Java, a webapp context running in a Tomcat server, on what is intended to be a load-balanced cluster of GCE instances.

And all of these instances share several common storage buckets, and a common Second Generation MySQL instance for their database.

Now, the developer who's in charge of the webapp ran an experimental cluster in his own private Google Cloud project, in which he just opened up the SQL server to the world, and didn't bother with any SSL. But obviously that's not going to fly as we get closer to the real thing.

I'm trying to get closer to the real thing. But how am I supposed to set up the database connections, when I don't know what IP addresses the GCE instances will have?

Looking at the "Authorization" tab for my MySQL instance, I see:

> **App Engine authorization**
>   All apps in this project are authorized by default. To authorize apps in other projects,
>   follow the steps below.
>   Apps in this project: All authorized.

But that's "App Engine." *Not* Google Compute Engine.

And I see something called "JDBC Socket Factory," but it's on a page about connecting from applications running *outside* of Google Cloud.

And I see a page about connecting the MySQL Client on a Google Compute instance (which begs the question, "why would I want to do *that*, when I can connect from my desktop, via something a bit more user-friendly?"). *Not* connecting a Tomcat webapp context running on a dynamically created instance.

What am I missing here?

---

I've been experimenting with the Proxy now, and I find that I can connect if the proxy is running under my account, but not if it's running under either of two service accounts that should also be able to connect.

In all three cases, the proxy starts, and is waiting for connections. If I'm running the proxy as myself, I can connect just fine, whether from the default MySQL client, or from Sequel Pro, or from Squirrel. But if I'm running the proxy from either the default service account, or a service account I created specifically for this, the client gets:

> MySQL said: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial
>   communication packet', system error: 0

and the proxy shows:

```
2018/03/22 09:38:23 New connection for "<REDACTED>"
2018/03/22 09:38:24 couldn't connect to "<REDACTED>": ensure that the
account has access to "<REDACTED>" (and make sure there's no typo in 
that name). Error during createEphemeral for <REDACTED>: googleapi: 
Error 403: Access Not Configured. Cloud SQL Administration API has
not been used in project 773874261491 before or it is disabled.
Enable it by visiting
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com
/o erview?project=<REDACTED> then retry. If you enabled this API
recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our
systems and retry., accessNotConfigured
```

I have:

- Cloud SQL Admin
- Cloud SQL Client
- Compute Instance Admin (v1)
- Compute Network Admin
- Compute Security Admin
- Deployment Manager Editor
- Service Account Actor
- Service Account Admin
- Service Account Key Admin
- Project IAM Admin
- Storage Admin

The default service account has:

- Cloud SQL Client Editor

The service account I created has:

- Cloud SQL Client

At a suggestion to try re-enabling the Cloud SQL API, I had it disabled and re-enabled. No change. Still:

```
Jamess-Mac-mini:~ jamesl$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<REDACTED>=tcp:3306
2018/03/22 09:37:42 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for <REDACTED>
2018/03/22 09:37:42 Ready for new connections
{Sequel Pro connected just fine}
2018/03/22 09:37:50 New connection for "<REDACTED>"
2018/03/22 09:37:52 New connection for "<REDACTED>"
2018/03/22 09:38:01 Client closed local connection on 127.0.0.1:3306
2018/03/22 09:38:01 Client closed local connection on 127.0.0.1:3306
^C
Jamess-Mac-mini:~ jamesl$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<REDACTED>=tcp:3306 -credential_file=<REDACTED my new service account>.json
2018/03/22 09:38:19 using credential file for authentication; email=<REDACTED my new service account>
2018/03/22 09:38:19 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for <REDACTED>
2018/03/22 09:38:19 Ready for new connections
{Sequel Pro failed to connect}
2018/03/22 09:38:23 New connection for "<REDACTED>"
2018/03/22 09:38:24 couldn't connect to "<REDACTED>": ensure that the
account has access to "<REDACTED>" (and make sure there's no typo in
that name). Error during createEphemeral for <REDACTED>: googleapi: 
Error 403: Access Not Configured. Cloud SQL Administration API has
not been used in project 773874261491 before or it is disabled.
Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?project=<REDACTED>
then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured
^C
Jamess-Mac-mini:~ jamesl$ ./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=<REDACTED>=tcp:3306 -credential_file=<REDACTED default service account>.json
2018/03/22 09:46:41 using credential file for authentication; email=<REDACTED default service account>
2018/03/22 09:46:41 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for <REDACTED>
2018/03/22 09:46:41 Ready for new connections
{Sequel Pro failed to connect}
2018/03/22 09:46:45 New connection for "<REDACTED>"
2018/03/22 09:46:46 couldn't connect to "<REDACTED>": ensure that the account has access to "<REDACTED>" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during createEphemeral for <REDACTED>: googleapi: Error 403: Access Not Configured. Cloud SQL Administration API has not been used in project <REDACTED> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?project=<REDACTED> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine#gce-connect-proxy) when the source IP of the Compute Engine instance might be changing. Step 8 of the guide explains how to start the proxy and you can use the mysql client (step 9) to test the connection from the GCE instance.

Once the proxy is setup, in the [connection URL](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database), use 'localhost' as it will be the proxy that will do the connection on 127.0.0.1. This in case you use a TCP socket connection, it's different if you use Unix sockets.